# Add Chrome profile specific shortcuts to Windows 10 start menu tiles

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome

I have multiple Google Chrome profiles (e.g. "Work" and "Home"). Chrome will create desktop shortcuts for these, called `<profile name> - Chrome` using the Chrome icon combined with the profile avatar, e.g.

[image]

But how can I put this shortcut in the start menu properly? If I right click them and select "Pin to Start", I get this.

[image]

Comment: Essentially, you would like to see the traditional icon.  Try to copy the shortcut to your `All Apps` list in the following location:  `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`.  If the icon still appears normally you can potentially right-click that shortcut within the alphabetical `All Apps` list and select `Pin to Start`.  Hopefully that will retain the Google Chrome icon.

Comment: Well the same icon and name as the proper shortcut not this "W~Chrome." thing. Will investigate the Start Menu directory when back on the system, maybe it works differently to the desktop and retains the shortcuts own icon and name.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late, but what I did to make it appear in the Start Menu is:

1. Copy/cut the Chrome profile shortcut from the Desktop
2. Paste the shortcut in:

   ```
   %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
   ```

Comment: Fortunately, it works not only for Crome Profiles, but for any desktop icon. Particularly, it worked for the icons of applications without installer (so called portable). This is exactly what I pursued.